# Should I upload ts (typescript) file or the generated js file or both

Tags: javascript, typescript

I just started having fun with TypeScript coming from previous experience with C# and one question is going through my mind.

When publishing a web site, app etc. that uses TypeScript which files should be uploaded on the host, the .ts, .js or all (.ts, .js + .js.map)?

Comment: In most cases you only upload 1 js file (that contains all your generated javascript concatenated and minified).

Answer (score 3):

The .js file. The .ts is the file that was compiled to JavaScript, and the browser only speaks .js.

Answer (score 2):

Your browser only understands JavaScript so you could upload that.

Alternatively, if you are doing Continuous Integration, you could commit only the TS files and have your task runner (Gulp/Grunt etc) call out to the TypeScript compiler and generate your JavaScript files, and then deploy.

Comment: Can you recommend an help article about such "task runner". I am new to the web programming so this might be a newb question.

Comment: Grunt has a decent getting started guide at http://gruntjs.com/getting-started, though talking about CI and task runners in answer to this question seems a bit far fetched. If you're just starting out, know that the browser only deals in javascript files and your typescript files are the equivalent of you C# source code before compilation. You can dive into the rest later without worry.